# redelivery after ACK

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

Why are my RabbitMQ messages being redelivered to my consumer after they have been ACKd? I'm new to RabbitMQ; I must be misusing it, or there's something wrong perhaps with the Ruby amqp gem.

I have a ruby script that subscribes to a queue and acks each message. If I let it make it all the way through the messages, the messages really do disappear from the queue; they're not redelivered. But if I interrupt my script before they're all ACKd, and then start the script again, delivery starts anew from the first message.

The behavior I'm seeing in code is reflected accurately by the RabbitMQ web management interface; the queue has messages, and despite the ACKs, they don't disappear.

Clue: I put about 5000 messages in the queue. If I let the consumer ACK a significant amount, a few messages do actually appear to be removed from the queue (contrary to what I said above). I haven't been able to nail this phenomenon down.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3, RabbitMQ 2.8.7, and the amqp ruby gem 0.9.8. It happens with producer and consumer on Ubuntu 12.0.4, or on Mac OS 10.7.4.

What the heck??

(See update at the end of this message)

Here's the code for the consumer:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "rubygems"
require 'amqp'
require 'aws-sdk'

queue_name = "some.queue"
begin
  AMQP.start("amqp://localhost:5672") do | connection |
    channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    queue = channel.queue(queue_name, :durable => true)
    queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do | metadata, payload |
      metadata.ack
    end
  end
end
```

and here's the producer:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "rubygems"
require 'amqp'
require 'aws-sdk'

msg = ARGV[0]
queue_name = "some.queue"
begin
  AMQP.start("amqp://localhost:5672") do | connection |
    channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    queue    = channel.queue(queue_name, :durable => true)
    (1..5000).each do | x |
      channel.default_exchange.publish x, :routing_key => queue_name, :persistent => true
    end
  end
end
```

With Wireshark I determined that the acks I was sending weren't being sent to the broker. I called metadata.ack, but no packets were sent.

Based on @Robthewolf's advice, I tried channel.prefetch(1). When I used that call, every ack made it to the broker. In general, if I called channel.prefetch(n), then once I had sent n (or sometimes n+1) acks, it sent them to the broker.

So I have a new question: why does prefetch() parameter determine how many acks must be sent before they are finally sent to the broker?

Comment: try https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-amqp/SoLiPMv8XI8

You might also try using channel.acknowledge(metadata.delivery_tag, false) and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unacked messages will be returned to the queue if your consumer is stopped. If only a few are acked they will not be returned to the queue but the others will be.
you can use `channel.basicQos(1);` to make sure that you only read 1 item at a time off the queue.  No new item will be read until the first item is acked.

Comment: Rob, as I've noted, I'm ACKing the messages, yet they are still being redelivered. I'm not sure if the basicQos(..) method is relevant. I'd try it, but I don't see its equivalent in the Ruby AMQP gem - any idea?

Comment: try the basic qos thing.  If that works great if not let me know

Comment: you will probably need to ask your follow up question as a new question